# Difference between $scope and scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs. I would like to know what is the difference between `$scope` in angularjs Controller and `scope` in angularjs Directive.

I tried to use scope in controller and I got the below error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: scopeProvider <- scope

Comment: This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/-w6FAkpDYzM) is useful for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$scope` is a service provided by `$scopeProvider`. You can inject it into controllers, directives or other services using Angular's built-in dependency injector:

`module.controller(function($scope) {...})`

which is shorthand for

`module.controller(['$scope', function($scope) {...}])`

In the first version the Dependency Injector *infers* the name of the provider ("$scopeProvider") based on the name of the function parameter ("$scope" + "Provider").
The second version also builds the provider name like that but uses the *explicit* `'$scope'` in the array, not the function parameter name. That means you can use any parameter name instead of `$scope`.

Thus you end up with code like this:
`module.controller(['$scope', function(scope) {...}])`
where `scope` could be anything, it's a function parameter name, could be `foo` or `a12342saa`.

The dependency injector basically does this:

```
function controller(def) {
    //def[def.length-1] is the actual controller function
    // everything before are it's dependencies

    var dependencies = [];
    for(dep in def.slice(0, def.length-1)) {
         dependencies.push(__get_dependency_by_name(dep));
    }
    def[def.length-1].apply(dependencies);
}
```

I think the reason why using "scope" instead of "$scope" as a dependency name won't work is clear now. There's no "scopeProvider" defined.

Comment: thanks i am able to get the dependency injector's working but i would like to know about the isolated scope , why we are using an isolate scope in directives instead of $scope

Comment: An isolated scope is still a scope. Read the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive