# What does the scope mean with fromTemplateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can someone tell me where I can find the documentation to explain what scope means in the following (or if there is another way..ie reading code etc. - I am a Ionic newbie so still trying to work out where things are.)

```
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {
       scope: $scope,
   }).then(function(modal) {
       $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```

So it is the scope: $scope that is confusing me.

Comment: might this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234637/difference-between-scope-and-scope-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the scope passed in will be the scope bound to the template.

It works pretty much exactly like any other scope.

If you had

```
$scope.items = [{name:"Dan", id:"1"}, {name:"Adam", id:"2"}]
```

You could render those in the template presented in the modal by referencing items.

Does that make sense?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that there can be multiple scopes in the template depending on what is in it so I was expecting the scope to be the parent scope of the controller.